# tkinter: How to pass arguments when <<ComboboxSelected>> is bound to a method?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, combobox, ttk

I am a newbie with the tkinter library and I don't understand how to pass arguments from a combobox to a method I would like to bind on event action?

Example:

```py
class Controller():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.view = View(self.root)
        self.view.sidepanel.motor_sel_combo.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>",  lambda event, arg=self.view.sidepanel.motor_sel_combo.get(): self.motor_selection(event, arg))
    
    def motor_selection(self,event, mot_selected):
        #print(event) #--> would only print <VirtualEvent event x=0 y=0> #????
        #print(event.widget.get())
        print(mot_selected)
```

The output for `print(mot_selected)` is empty. The tkinter manual does not show a good example.

`self.view.sidepanel.motor_sel_combo.get()` contains the imho the selected value of the combobox.

I tried as well with `functools.partial` instead of `lambda`, but I don't get it to work.
Could you show me the correct syntax with `lambda` and `functools.partial`, please?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `self.view.sidepanel.motor_sel_combo.get()` at the time you create the lambda, not at the time the combobox value has changed.

You should call the `get()` method inside the function instead of trying to pass it to the function. The use of `lambda` here does nothing but make the code unnecessarily complex.

```
class Controller():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.view = View(self.root)
        self.view.sidepanel.motor_sel_combo.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>",  
            self.motor_selection)
    
    def motor_selection(self,event):
        mot_selected = self.view.sidepanel.motor_sel_combo.get()
        ...
```

It was pointed out in a comment by @acw1668 that the function should use `event.widget.get()` instead of `self.view.sidepanel.motor_sel_combo.bet()` and that is true. Since we want to call `get()` on the widget that was bound, using the shorter version is the better solution. It is better for two reasons: because it makes the function [loosely coupled](https://nordicapis.com/the-difference-between-tight-coupling-and-loose-coupling/) to the other code, and because it makes it more clear that the function is operating on the widget it was bound to. That means that the other code could rename that variable and the function will continue to work without having to also be modified.

For such a small program, whether the function is loosely coupled or tightly coupled isn't that big of a deal. I would argue, though, that using `event.widget` in a callback is a best practice that one should get in the habit of doing.

The OP indicated in comments they want to see a version that uses `lambda`. I don't recommend it, but the root of the problem with `lambda` is that the OP was calling the `get()` method when defining the `lambda` rather than when it is called. To call the `get()` method when the `lambda` runs, the call must be moved inside the body:

```
self.view.sidepanel.motor_sel_combo.bind(
    "<<ComboboxSelected>>",  
    lambda event: self.motor_selection(event, self.view.sidepanel.motor_sel_combo.get())
)
```

In this case, `motor_selection` must be like in the OP's original code and accept two parameters.

Comment: It is better to use `mot_selected = event.widget.get()`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I came up with this solution in my tries, but I thought it is a bad style.  Should we not call by value instead of reference? Why can I not pass the value through the function signature, please? Could you show me a solution for this scenario, please? I would love to see a solution with `lambda` and `partial` if you would be so kind. Much appreciated. I realised I could also `event.widget.get()` to access the value, but I am not sure what is better.

Comment: @acw1668 Yes, I found this out, too. Thank you. I would really love to understand/see a solution with `partial` and `lambda`. I think this could be useful in the future for my gui.

Comment: @PythonSmurf: you're asking us for a suboptimal way of doing it? I can assure you, this is the best practice.

Comment: @PythonSmurf I wonder why you think that using `partial` and `lambda` is a better way in this situation.

Comment: Still, I would like to know, please. If you can show both examples with `lambda` and `partial`, I would appreciated it. Why do you say it is suboptimal?

Comment: @acw1668: First, I would like to see a version with `partial`, `lambda` to know all options. Then I can select. Also, would there be a difference between  `event.widget.get()` and `self.view.sidepanel.motor_sel_combo.get()`? There are examples on StackOverflow, but I don't get them here to work. I think it would be more useful to pass multiple arguments to my motor_selection function later.

Comment: @PythonSmurf: in this case there is no difference between the two ways of calling the `get()` method. `event.widget.get()` is a good habit to get into, because it less tightly couples the implementation of this function to the remainder of the code. If you renamed the widget, `event.widget.get()` would still work.

Comment: @BryanOakley: Thank you! I just see both ways are useful. If a function is bound to the widget, I can access the value directly with `event.widget.get()`. If another function is not directly bound to the event, but I need to ask for the combobox value, I access it via `self.view.sidepanel.motor_sel_combo.get()`

Comment: @BryanOakley I can see you updated your answer. Many thanks! Could help me still and show it with `partial`, please? I was not successful with my tries. I am just curious to understand how it works. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: @BryanOakley: Why does your lambda function has only event as param and nothing for the `mot_selected` ? I thought I have to give also the `lambda` two parameters, one for even, one for the `mot_selected`.

Comment: @PythonSmurf: it only has a single parameter because the event only passes a single parameter.

Comment: @PythonSmurf: You can't really do it with `functools.partial` since you need to wait to call the `get` function until after the event fires. `functools.partial` is good for adding parameters that exist before the function is called.

Comment: @BryanOakley Thank you very much for the discussion with you.
"it only has a single parameter because the event only passes a single parameter.": Even if the bound function wants to get two arguments? I thought the `lambda` adapts to the receiving function, i.e. `event` and `mot_selected` as arguments.

Comment: @PythonSmurf: `lambda` doesn't adapt to anything. It is up to you to have it accept the correct arguments and pass them on to the body of the function.

Comment: @BryanOakley: My original function was `motor_selection(self,event, mot_selected)`, 2 input args, `event`, `mot_selected`. Your `lambda` function above has only event as argument. What happens please to `mot_selected`? after `eveent`  I thought it had to be `lambda a,b: fun(a,b)`. Thank you.

Comment: @PythonSmurf: `lambda a,b: fun(a,b)` is the correct way to do it when you know `a` and `b` ahead of time. You don't. Your problem is that `b` must be computed after the function is called, not before. When the even triggers, it sends one parameter. That's all you need, the function already has access to everything else it needs.

Comment: @acw1668 Do you know a manual where I could see the methods available like ` event.widget.get()` please? Thank you